# R - write.foreign to SPSS => console hangs?

Tags: r, spss

When I run below write.foreign command in R, the console shows a plus sign, not the command prompt, and stays that way until I hit escape.

```
x<-(1:5)
y<-c("y","y","y","n","n")
testdat<-data.frame(x,y)
names(testdat)<-c("var1","var2")
setwd("C:\\temp")
write.foreign(testdat, "mydata.sav", "mydata.sps",   package="SPSS)
```

I'm new to R so maybe I am missing something obvious?

I'm running R Studio on a 64 bit windows 7 machine
R version 3.1.1

Thanks

Comment: `package="SPSS)` - You're missing a closing `"` after `"SPSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues

- missing closing " after "SPSS (thanks nrussel-.
- foreign needs an explicit path to the to be saved files

This works:

```
write.foreign(testdat, "C:\\temp\\mydata.dat", "C:\\temp\\mydata.sps",   package="SPSS")
```

You need the path for the mydata.sps file to work.